# Edit .txt file using forms in html php

Tags: php, html, forms, file-handling

I have written a program in php,html. I have created a form and I can save the form inputs in a .txt file.The thing is I need to write a code where I can edit my .txt file inputs and save them again with the changes. Can you help me out? This is the code I have written.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="bug.php">
    <label>Emri produktit:</label>
    <input type="text" name="emriprod" id="emriprod">
    <label>Versioni</label>
    <input type="text" name="versioni" id="versioni">
    <label>Frekuenca</label>
    <input type="text" name="frekuenca" id="frekuenca">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**bug.php**

```
<?php
$emriprod=$_POST["emriprod"];
$versioni=$_POST["versioni"];
$frekuenca=$_POST["frekuenca"];
$fp=fopen("bug.txt","a");
$string=$emriprod." ".$versioni." ".$frekuenca."\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $string);
fclose($fp);
echo "Te dhenat u ruajten ne file";
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is `bug.txt` in a location PHP can access?

Comment: This code works fine but it is just for adding inputs from form to .txt file.I need  to write a code so I can modify the inputs I have added to the .txt file with the help of another form

Comment: any special reason why you're not using a database? Handling files is a lot of work.

Comment: I'm studying for an exam and I have to use files

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data with special characters to separate the fields .

```
$string = $emriprod."@#".$versioni."@#".$frekuenca."\r\n";
```

Retrieving the data

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('bug.txt');
$data = $explode('@#', $file_data); //separating the string to array
```

After you editing the existing data, update the file like below

```
file_put_contents('bug.txt',str_replace('old data','new_data',file_get_contents('bug.txt')));
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: I know how to do this. The question is how can I retrieve the data from the .txt file, modify it and then save it again in the .txt file

Comment: Hello can you please explain how do I edit the data? Cause I dont know how to do that.I mean I want to change it using a form

Comment: @Malv $data variable has the existing values in array format. I mean [0=> 'value1', 1 => 'value2', 2 => 'value3']; You can put these values in edit form.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Are you still looking for help